# Grails fails to start up, "downloading tomcat-embed..."

Tags: maven, grails

Symptoms:

```
Grails was stuck on 
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar
```

... and would not advance.

Environment:
Laptop with Intellij 12.0.1, Windows 7 Home Premium, Grails 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

- I turned off windows firewall through control panel - no help I added
  'log "verbose"' to BuildConfig.groovy - It didn't help.  It just
  added more information *before* | Downloading:
  tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar
- I deleted the IVY cache file under
  c:\Users\Me.grails - Getting close.  Delete failed. I found "Java"
  tasks in task manager and killed them.  Now I can copy the relevant
  jar into place after downloading from the URL in verbose output! 
  Still no dice on grails startup, though (because of the next
  dependency).
- I stopped AVG temporarily - no help.
- I went back to Windows Firewall and found a "... with Advanced Security" link.
- I disabled the "domain profile" security (my earlier actions had disabled "public profile" and "private profile")...  Now grails starts up appropriately.  But firewall is disabled, not the best solution.

From here, the correct solution became obvious.  I had accidentally mis-categorized my home network as "Public" and even after I plugged in an ethernet cable Windows used the wireless security settings.  Simply disabling the wireless network or reclassifying it allowed me to reset windows security settings without disabling grails.